# How to insert many rows of data from arrays/lists to SQL Server (DataSet, DataTable)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, dataset

I need little help with transferring data from variables, arrays, lists to my SQL Server.

Im not bad in SQL, but im not familiar with DataSet, DataTable objects.

My data is now stored in list of strings (List). Every string in that list looks similar to this:

> QWERTY,19920604,0.91,0.35,0.34,0.35,343840

There are about 900000 rows like this, but big import will happen only once.

Target datatypes in SQL Server:

```
BIGINT (primary key, im not inserting it, its identity(1,1))
VARCHAR(10), 
DATE, 
DECIMAL(10,2), 
DECIMAL(10,2), 
DECIMAL(10,2), 
DECIMAL(10,2), 
INT
```

1. How to convert that data to SQL Server data types?
2. How to insert that data into SQL Server? Also i need some progress bar updates between inserts.

I could do this using old-fashion SQL command, 
but i finally have learn more modern way, **by using DataTable** object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did shomething like this:

```
foreach (string currentrow in buffer) // List<string> buffer - contains csv data
{
                // table name is Import
                dataset.ImportRow row = dataset.Import.NewImportRow();
                string[] fields = new string[7];

                // Field names
                // <Nm>,<Date>,<Open>,<High>,<Low>,<Close>,<Vol>
                fields = currentrow.Split(',');

                // ticker
                row.Nm = fields[0];

                DateTime data;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out data);
                row.Date = data;

                decimal open;
                Decimal.TryParse(fields[2], out open);
                row.Open = open;

                decimal high;
                Decimal.TryParse(fields[3], out high);
                row.High = high;

                decimal low;
                Decimal.TryParse(fields[4], out low);
                row.Low = low;

                decimal close;
                Decimal.TryParse(fields[5], out close);
                row.Close = close;

                int vol;
                Int32.TryParse(fields[6], out vol);
                row.Vol = vol;

                dataset.Import.AddImportRow(row);

            }

        importTableAdapter.Update(dataset);
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

It works and looks elegant. I have to work on exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

you can use sqlbulkcopy, here are some examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a.aspx

Comment: For educational purposes i prefer to do it manually by DataTable object.

Comment: for large size data, bulkcopy is the right way to do. you can use insert to insert line by line, but it is much slower and inefficient.

Comment: Large size data will be only first import. Later i will import only new data (100 rows at once).

Answer (score 1):

I just starting moving over to the entity framework which has greatly reduced my code complexity. To do so I added a new datasource using the entity framework via the following steps:

1. Add a new datasource
2. In the Datasource configuration wizard, choose Database
3. Choose Entity Data Model
4. Choose Generate from Database
5. Create a new connection
6. Select your tables and click finish

Compile your project so your objects are available for you to use, then within your code you can create your access via:

`var entity = new DatabaseEntity();`

Within entity you will now see a series of your tables and various methods to use. To perform an you can use linq like:

```
var order = new entity.fulfilled_shipments_data
                    {
                         addedCustomer = 0,
                         addedFulfillment = 0,
                         addedInvoice = 0,
                          ...
                     }
entity.fulfilled_shipments_data.AddObject(order);
entity.SaveChanges();
```

Keep in mind your assignment can now be any object you have, and may also include calls to other methods (for example, `price = Convert.ToDecimal(price),`)

Comment: Where i can find DatabaseEntity type? Im using .net 3.5.

Comment: I dont have Entity Data Model in my VS2008 Std. I assume i have to download something. I give up that method. Ill try with DataTable alone.

Comment: @Kamil now u have a good reason to upgrade to visual studio 2010 :)

Answer (score 0):

With ADO.NET, probably the easiest and most fail-safe is to use a loop:

```
private void InsertList(IEnumerable<String> list)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table VALUES(@varcharCol,@dateCol,@decCol1,@decCol2,@decCol3,@decCol4,@intCol);";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        foreach (String str in list)
        {
            String[] fields = str.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (fields.Length == 7)
            { 
                DateTime dateCol;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateCol))
                {
                    decimal d1, d2, d3, d4;
                    int i1;
                    if(decimal.TryParse(fields[2], out d1)
                        && decimal.TryParse(fields[3], out d2)
                        && decimal.TryParse(fields[4], out d3)
                        && decimal.TryParse(fields[5], out d4)
                        && int.TryParse(fields[6], out i1))
                    {
                        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varcharCol", fields[0]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateCol", dateCol);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decCol1", d1);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decCol2", d2);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decCol3", d3);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decCol4", d4);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intCol", i1);
                            int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // should be 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should add logging(parsing problems) and exception handling (connection problems).

This approach also enables to add a progress bar easily. Therefore you could use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which updates a `Progressbar` via [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx).

Here's a tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Comment: You did not read to the end. I dont want to use sql command. I want to learn modern way with DataTable, LINQ (?).

Comment: A `DataTable` + `DataAdapter` is just a wrapper around an `InsertCommand` like above. It's basically the same and even unnecessary overhead in this case. The loop above also enables to trigger progress changes or add logs entries/exception handling. So even if part of the list is corrupted the rest works.

Comment: Btw, the method above should work as it is. ADO.NET is not outdated and has still it's place if you want to have all under control without overhead. Linq is a query tool and is not an alternative.